# Control variables to be fetched on VF so as to utilize view state space

Tags: visualforce, viewstate

I have a doubt on having/pulling variables on VF. Lets say I have 2 scenarios in VF page. The second one is dependent on first one's condition.

So, is there any way, to flush out 1st scenario's unused variables(which will not be used in 2nd scenario) and then only allow VF to fetch those variables on page(so as to save view state/utilize it properly).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use `transient` keyword in the declaration of variables which you don't need.

Comment: No I cannot use that, as I need to flow those variables to server side.

Comment: Try to use more HTML components and less VF components since they also contribute to view state size. More tips can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_performance.htm)

Comment: It is hard to guess how to optimise your page without proper overview of it. Probably, if code is available, more productive suggestions can be made

Comment: It could be one solution which can be thought while designing/writing new one. However, I am specifically concerned about "Flushing/Removing"some variables from view state or loading new variables on VF based on conditions; which will be used to address issue in developed components.

Comment: Then as @kurunve said without code it's hard to give you any kind of solution.

Comment: Setting the fields used in the first page that are not needed in the second page to null will stop content ending up in the second page's view state.

Comment: @KeithC thanks, it can be used in existing ecosystem as well!